# building a function with string search logic in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a function which takes a `product` and checks whether that string contains a category in `categories` list. The check should not be case-sensitive, but when the first match is found the function should return the value as it is given in the list. If the product does not contain any of the categories the string 'Other' should be returned.

Example:
if `product = Debit card` and `categories = ['Account', 'Card', 'Debit']`
then `assign_category(product, categories)` will return `Card`.

This is the base code:

```
def assign_category(product, categories):
    for x in range(len(categories)):
        if categories[x] == product:
            return product
        return 'Other'
```

I'm struggling to find a way for the function to take account of the word, when it isn't exactly entered as so.
The list is: `['Reporting', 'Card', 'Account', 'Debt', 'Loan', 'Mortgage']`

one entry in the list to break down is `Debit cards` so it should return `Card`

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please paste some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `title()` for non case-sensitive check and use `in` to search the category in the product. You should also return the category, not the product. The `return 'Other'` statment should be outside the 'for' loop. like this:

```py
def assign_category(product, categories):
    for x in range(len(categories)):
        if categories[x] in product.title():
            return categories[x]
    return 'Other'
```

I also recommend looping through `categories` and not `range(len(categories))` (redundent according to the question) like this:

```py
def assign_category(product, categories):
    for category in categories:
        if category in product.title():
            return category
    return 'Other'
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare both product and category in lowercase

```
categories = ['Reporting', 'Card', 'Account', 'Debt', 'Loan', 'Mortgage']

def assign_category(product, categories):
    product = product.lower()
    for category in categories:
        if category.lower() in product:
            return category
    return 'Other'
```

```
>>> assign_category("Debit card", categories)
'Card'
```